# Saving a stream in TempData MVC5 C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Hi i am uploading a large file using asp.net mvc5 to server and in controler i am saving this stream into TempData.on my local machine it is working fine and successfully uploading large files.but on hosted server it fails.i have tried it with increasing MaxAllowedContent and ExcutionTimeOut Limit but none of them worked.Can anyone help me on this.

Here is my controller action

```
 public ActionResult UploadTransactionPDF()
        {
        private readonly List<MemoryStream> _PdfImage = new List<MemoryStream>();

        private readonly List<string> _PdfImageNames = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                Gateway.Instance.Logger.LogInfo(string.Format(_formatProvider,"[TransactionController  -> UploadTransactionPDF ]: method started : Save pdf to memory."));

                if (CheckFileExist())
                {
                    if (TempData[TransactionRef.PdfFiles.ToString()] != null)
                    {
                        _PdfImage.Clear();
                        _PdfImage.AddRange(TempData[TransactionRef.PdfFiles.ToString()] as List<MemoryStream>);
                    }

                    if (TempData[TransactionRef.PdfFileName.ToString()] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TempData[TransactionRef.PdfFileName.ToString()].ToString()))
                    {
                        _PdfImageNames.Clear();
                        _PdfImageNames.AddRange(TempData[TransactionRef.PdfFileName.ToString()] as List<string>);
                    }

                    for (int a = 0; a < Request.Files.Count; a++)
                    {
                        if (!_PdfImageNames.Contains(Request.Files[a].FileName))
                        {
                            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                            Request.Files[a].InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                            _PdfImage.Add(ms);
                            _PdfImageNames.Add(Request.Files[a].FileName);
                        }
                    }

                    TempData[TransactionRef.PdfFiles.ToString()] = _PdfImage;
                    TempData[TransactionRef.PdfFileName.ToString()] = _PdfImageNames;
                    ViewBag.Info = "pdf";
                    ViewBag.ImageUploadInfo = Language.ImageSavedMessage.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.ImageUploadInfo = Language.NoFileMessage.ToString();
                }

                ViewBag.FileNames = _PdfImageNames;
                Gateway.Instance.Logger.LogInfo(string.Format(_formatProvider, "[TransactionController  -> UploadTransactionPDF ] : method exited ."));
                return View("_PDFFiles");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorInfo = string.Format(_formatProvider, "[TransactionController  -> UploadTransactionPDF ]  : Error : '{0}' occurred while saving pdf to memory.",ex.Message);
                Gateway.Instance.Logger.LogError(errorInfo,ex);
                throw new Exception(errorInfo, ex);
            }
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What error message did you receive on the hosted server?

Comment: Hi Jeff when i am clicking on Add button for the same it takes a lot time around 2 minutes then connection time out error is coming up.

Comment: Hi Jeff when i am clicking on Add button for the same it takes a lot time around 2 minutes (on production server only on my local machine it is fine) then connection time out error is coming up. I am also showing you my config file Under <System.Web> tab i have <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="1024" maxRequestLength="1048576"/> and  <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="204800000" />
      </requestFiltering>

Answer (score 0):

can you see if the following exists in your web.config on the dev enviroment versus on the server. ddddd should be the max your request should allow. don't make it to high to where you open yourself up for DOS. the request length wouldn't just be the file size but the entire request from the client to the server.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="ddddd" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

you can localize it to the one controller action by adding a location element in between the configuration and system.web elements.

Comment: Hi Bozman thanks for ur response.i have tried this as well after your suggestion .below are the different set of config values that i tried but none of them worked for me.                                                  <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800"/>


<httpRuntime executionTimeout="999999" maxRequestLength="512000" />

<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="204800" requestLengthDiskThreshold="204800" />

<httpRuntime maxUrlLength="1024" targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="999999" maxRequestLength="1048576" requestLengthDiskThreshold="1048576" />

Comment: those should have covered it. Have you checked the virtual memory limit on the app pool itself? It could be recycling and losing the request. IIS -> application pools -> choose correct app pool -> advanced settings and at the bottom there should be a setting called virtual memory limit (kb) and make sure that is 0 for unlimited.